# How to change extension of file using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have few list of links with .pdf extensions,i want when user click on that link whole text of link get stored in variable.
from that variable i want to repalce .pdf to .jpg
i tried

```
$(".links").click(function() {

  var clickedId= $(this).text();
  document.getElementById("thumb_url").value = "educroc.com/thumbs/"+clickedId+'.jpg';
```

eg: 
i have list
`<a href="#"> 1.pdf</a>`

when user  click on it `clickedId=1.pdf`
my result is : `1.pdf.jpg`
required result is : `1.jpg`

Comment: `string.replace(/\.pdf/i, '.jpg');`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".links").click(function() {

  var clickedId= $(this).text();
  clickedId = clickedId.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""); // it will remove any extension from name
  document.getElementById("thumb_url").value = "educroc.com/thumbs/"+clickedId+'.jpg';  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the extension of the file, you want to change the string from the link from ".pdf" to ".jpg".

You can use jQuery to get the name of your file and replace it, like this:

```
$(".links").click(function() {
    var clickedId= $(this).text();
    var url = $('#thumb_url').html(); // bla/bla/bla.pdf
    var split = url.split('.');
    split[split.length - 1] = 'jpg'; // Last position of split is the extension
    var newUrl = split.join('.');
    $('#thumb_url').html(newUrl);
```

```

Although you probably want to change the href attribute rather the content of the  ;)